# how to stop abb rbot when sensor values reaches a particular limit

Tags: ros, rviz, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using abb 2400 model which can do path planning. i wrote a node which can read ultrasonic sensor values and it displays a marker according to the sensor value.The robot is executing a plan continously .I want to stop the robot when sensor value reaches a particular value. By using `state_display_time` we can do this in rviz explicitly. How to automatically do this , what changes need to be made in the node i have written.

The code is,

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
   #include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
   #include "sensor_msgs/Range.h"
#include "std_msgs/Bool.h"
#include "planning_display.h"
 //#include <arm_navigation_msgs/DisplayTrajectory.h>

 

 #include <map>

float range=1 ;
float t=1;
//range=1000;
int i=1;
void rangeCallback(const sensor_msgs::Range::ConstPtr& range_data)
{

  range = range_data->range;
 ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f]", range);
ros::NodeHandle n;
     ros::Rate r(1);
    ros::Publisher marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visualization_marker", 1);
 
    
 // Set our initial shape type to be a cube
     uint32_t shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;



     while (ros::ok())
     {
     // ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("range_data", 9600,rangeCallback);   
visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
       // Set the frame ID and timestamp.  See the TF tutorials for information on these.
       marker.header.frame_id = "/base_link";
       marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
   
       // Set the namespace and id for this marker.  This serves to create a unique ID
     // Any marker sent with the same namespace and id will overwrite the old one
       marker.ns = "basic_shapes";
       marker.id = 0;
   
       // Set the marker type.  Initially this is CUBE, and cycles between that and SPHERE, ARROW, and CYLINDER
       //marker.type = shape;
   marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::CYLINDER;
       // Set the marker action.  Options are ADD, DELETE, and new in ROS Indigo: 3 (DELETEALL)
     marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
       // Set the pose of the marker.  This is a full 6DOF pose relative to the frame/time specified in the header
 
       marker.pose.position.x =range; //TO MOVE MARKER
       marker.pose.position.y = 0;
       marker.pose.position.z = 1;  
       marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
       marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
       marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
       marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
  
       // Set the scale of the marker -- 1x1x1 here means 1m on a side
       marker.scale.x = 2.0;
       marker.scale.y = 2.0;
       marker.scale.z = 2.0;
   
       // Set the color -- be sure to set alpha to something non-zero!

       marker.color.r = 0.20f;
       marker.color.g = 0.3f;
       marker.color.b = 0.2f;
       marker.color.a = 1;
 
       marker.lifetime = ros::Duration();
   
       // Publish the marker
       while (marker_pub.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
       {
         if (!ros::ok())
         {
           return ;
         }
        // ROS_WARN_ONCE("Please create a subscriber to the marker");
      
sleep(1);
       }
       marker_pub.publish(marker);
   
       // Cycle between different shapes
       /*switch (4)
       {
       case visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE:
         shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE;
        break;
      case visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE:
        shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
        break;
      case visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW:
        shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CYLINDER;
        break;
      case visualization_msgs::Marker::CYLINDER:*/
       //shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CYLINDER;
      // break;
      //}
 
ros::spin();

   }
  
 
}
   int main( int argc, char** argv )
   {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_shapes");
     ros::NodeHandle n;
     ros::Rate r(1);
    //ros::Publisher marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visualization_marker", 1);
 
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("range_data", 9600,rangeCallback);   
ros::spin();
return 0;
//r.sleep();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247548/how-to-stop-abb-rbot-when-sensor-values-reaches-a-particular-limit/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sending an empty trajectory should cause the robot to stop.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0